# Which one needs to be plural

Tags: word-order

I have three noun words that will be constructed as a part of a title sentence. Consider:

> ........ using Shape properties means

And

> .......using Shape property means

1. The property is a quantity or say, a number. The are more than one shape properties of an object.
2. The Mean is an average

For example

**Object A:**

Property1

Peoperty2

Mean of those properties

**Object B**:

Property1

Peoperty2

Mean of those properties

Now I want turn it as a part of 'title' of my report in English

I do really need your assistances in choosing between

*Shape properties means* or *shape property means*?

Typically in a title, a word should be in a general sense, while talking about an object in general, needs to use a plural form. Now I'm really confused which one of those needs to be in a plural form or, eventually some of them need to be plural

Thank you for the time.

Comment: Do yourself (and your readers! :) a favour - use an alternative such as ***average*** or ***median** values*, rather than "awkward-to-parse" ***means***. Note that *syntactically*, all "nouns" before the last one in your [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) are normally specified in the ***singular*** (so ***shapes*** and/or ***properties*** are "incorrect").

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you should rather blame mathematics for that. Who asked it to choose such a ambiguous word. Haha. Thank very much for helping.

Comment: Don't be mean! - mathematicians didn't mean any harm. But I must say that  when they discovered (decided?!) that [***mean*** and ***median*** are different](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Mean_vs_Median), they could have done ***us*** all a favour by not publicising the fact! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As FumbleFingers points out in his comment, because "means" has a number of *meanings*, in this sentence it could confuse the reader.  There is no benefit to condensing a sentence into fewer words, if it makes it more difficult to understand.

Instead, talk about "the *average* of all of the ..." or something similar:

> **Taking** the **average** of the Shape properties, we find ...
>
> **Finding** the **median** of the Shape properties values, we can ...

Note that it is more idiomatic to *take* an average (meaning "calculate") rather than *use* an average, however this depends on exactly what you want to say.  In a title, for example, *use* might be better:

> **Using** Shape Property Averages (to Generate N-Sided Matrices)

Also note in the title I used the singular *property* because it is the name of a particular *class* of objects.

There may be better ways to phrase your title, but you have to tell us the entire title before we can give you any advice.